# can i execute a method in a controller without routes in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter-4

so in codeigniter 4 when you want to execute a method from a controller you need to change the url for an example if you want to execute a method called 'savedata' you change the url to 'save' and then inside the file routes i write this line of code

```
$routes->post('/save', 'Controller::savedata');
```

can i just directly execute it?

I'm sorry if this is poorly explained.

when i try to directly execute the method by using a link like `<a href="controller/savedata">save</a>` the result would be page not found

Comment: What do you mean by *"directly execute it"*?

Comment: To do that you would need to adjust your route definition to: `$routes->get('/controller/savedata', 'Controller::savedata');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need to **enable the Auto Routing feature** in your Routes.php and Feature.php config files.

Official doc and samples are here :
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/controllers.html#controller-auto-routing-improved

You could create a controller like this :

```
class Person extends BaseController
{
    public function getSave()
    {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

and call it like this :

```
<a href="person/save">Save</a>
```